# How to fix the scroll issue in Bootstrap 4 when one modal is closed and another open immediately after?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have code in my application that requires closing existing `modal` and immediately opening another `modal`. The code works fine, but there is a `scrolling issue` (vertical/horizontal) with the second modal. If I resize my screen and try to scroll vertically only background content is scrolling. I was digging to find the issue and here is what I found. I think there is a time race condition problem. If I put `setTime {...some code...,400}` that will fix the problem. I still believe there is a cleaner solution for this. Also, if some can explain why this is happening that would be great. Here is code example:

```js
var COMMON_FUNC = {};
COMMON_FUNC.dialogBox = function(title, message, size) {
  title = title || 'HCS System';
  message = message || 'HCS Dialog Box';
  size = size || 'lg';

  var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: true,
    backdrop: true,
    size: size,
    title: '<strong>' + title + '</strong>',
    message: message
  });
  dialog.prop("id", "dialog-box");
};

$("#open-modal-one").on("click", function() {
  var div = '<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary edit-record">Edit</button></div>'
  COMMON_FUNC.dialogBox("Modal One", div, "xl");
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit-record", function() {
  $("#dialog-box").modal("hide");
  //setTimeout(function(){$("#second_modal").modal("show");},400);
  $("#second_modal").modal("show");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is a test!</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" id="open-modal-one">Open Modal One</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="second_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Second Modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is second modal. If I try to scroll vertically only background will scroll.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `hide` events of the first modal and only once it done, to show the second.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit-record", function() {
  $("#dialog-box").one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#second_modal").modal("show");
  }).modal("hide");
});
```

Like this:

```js
var COMMON_FUNC = {};
COMMON_FUNC.dialogBox = function(title, message, size) {
  title = title || 'HCS System';
  message = message || 'HCS Dialog Box';
  size = size || 'lg';

  var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: true,
    backdrop: true,
    size: size,
    title: '<strong>' + title + '</strong>',
    message: message
  });
  dialog.prop("id", "dialog-box");
};

$("#open-modal-one").on("click", function() {
  var div = '<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary edit-record">Edit</button></div>'
  COMMON_FUNC.dialogBox("Modal One", div, "xl");
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit-record", function() {
  $("#dialog-box").one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#second_modal").modal("show");
  }).modal("hide");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is a test!</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" id="open-modal-one">Open Modal One</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="second_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Second Modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is second modal. If I try to scroll vertically only background will scroll.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Mosh, that solved the issue. I wasn't aware of that option/function that checks if previous modal is closed prior to opening another one. Thank you.